# Not able to update Bluej to 5.0.2

Tags: updates

I am not able to update my bluej, i had installed it earlier, and there is new version 5.0.2 released, i have installed the deb file but when i open it, it says `failed to installed: not supported` please help me, old version is much lagging [I have attached ubuntu software screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnlTP.png)

Comment: No info has been provided to help you. What version of Ubuntu? Did you check and see if the new version runs on your version of Ubuntu? I do not think you mean installed maybe downloaded?

Comment: BlueJ 5.0.2 is the [latest](https://www.bluej.org/) [version](https://repology.org/project/bluej/versions). Why do you think you have newer somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

To install [BlueJ](https://www.bluej.org/) open terminal and use commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.bluej.org/download/files/BlueJ-linux-502.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./BlueJ-linux-502.deb
```